# Update sql script dynamically

Tags: java

I'm working on requirement, where I have to run sql script. But behaviour of sql script is very dynamic because source table(DOD.PRODUCTS) is having dynamic schema. So when I merge that into target (BOB.PRODUCTS) in situation where one or more extra columns come in source then the below script should also be updated with new columns.

I'm looking for a way so that if new column arrives in source then how can I add the entry for that new column in below script at all places in most efficient way. My idea is just look for every position where column name needs to be added like in where clause, INSERT, VALUES etc. But am not happy wih this approach because its goona be very harsh code.

May I know any effective idea to update this script ? Code I can manage, I'm just looking for IDEA

```
MERGE INTO BOB.PRODUCTS GCA
        USING (SELECT * FROM DOD.PRODUCTS) SCA
        ON (SCA.CCOA_ID=GCA.CCOA_ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
        GCA.EFTV_TO=SYSDATE-1
        ,GCA.ROW_WRITTEN=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    WHERE (GCA.EFTV_TO IS NULL)
        AND(NVL(GCA.DESCR,'NULL')<>NVL(SCA.DESCR,'NULL')
        OR NVL(GCA.SHORT_DESCR,'NULL')<>NVL(SCA.SHORT_DESCR,'NULL')
        OR NVL(GCA.FREE_FRMT,'NULL')<>NVL(SCA.FREE_FRMT,'NULL')
        OR NVL(GCA.CCOI_ATT,'NULL')<>NVL(SCA.CCOI_ATT,'NULL'))
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT(CCOA_ID, DESCR, SHORT_DESCR, FREE_FRMT, CCOI_ATT, EFTV_FROM, EFTV_TO, ROW_WRITTEN
        )
        VALUES(SCA.CCOA_ID, SCA.DESCR, SCA.SHORT_DESCR, SCA.FREE_FRMT, SCA.CCOI_ATT, SYSDATE, NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
        );


INSERT INTO 
    BOB.PRODUCTS GCA(GCA.CCOA_ID, GCA.DESCR, GCA.SHORT_DESCR, GCA.FREE_FRMT, GCA.CCOI_ATT, GCA.EFTV_FROM, GCA.EFTV_TO, GCA.ROW_WRITTEN
    )
    SELECT SCA.CCOA_ID, SCA.DESCR, SCA.SHORT_DESCR, SCA.FREE_FRMT, SCA.CCOI_ATT, SYSDATE, NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 FROM DOD.PRODUCTS SCA 
LEFT OUTER JOIN BOB.PRODUCTS GCA
ON NVL(SCA.CCOA_ID,'NULL')=NVL(GCA.CCOA_ID,'NULL')
    AND NVL(SCA.DESCR,'NULL')=NVL(GCA.DESCR,'NULL')
    AND NVL(SCA.SHORT_DESCR,'NULL')=NVL(GCA.SHORT_DESCR,'NULL')
    AND NVL(SCA.FREE_FRMT,'NULL')=NVL(GCA.FREE_FRMT,'NULL')
    AND NVL(SCA.CCOI_ATT,'NULL')=NVL(GCA.CCOI_ATT,'NULL')
WHERE NVL(SCA.DESCR,'NULL')<>NVL(GCA.DESCR,'NULL')
    OR NVL(SCA.SHORT_DESCR,'NULL')<>NVL(GCA.SHORT_DESCR,'NULL')
    OR NVL(SCA.FREE_FRMT,'NULL')<>NVL(GCA.FREE_FRMT,'NULL')
    OR NVL(SCA.CCOI_ATT,'NULL')<>NVL(GCA.CCOI_ATT,'NULL');
```

Comment: Why are you doing this via a script at all? Can't you use the DB directly (JDBC)?

Comment: maybe this helps https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/criteria

Comment: I'd rather use Python instead of Java for that, but I think it could be fairly easy to *generate* (not update) the script given a list of columns.

Comment: If the schema is changing you will need to abstract what the queries are doing and then _regenerate_ the query every time the schema changes.  This could be simple if the scope of changes is minimal, or it could be a massive task.  Without a full understanding of the schema and the significance of the changes with regards to the business rules embodied in the queries we cannot really help.